# How to get the date and time from timestamp in PostgreSQL select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, timestamp

How to get the date and time only up to minutes, not seconds, from timestamp in PostgreSQL. I need date as well as time.

For example:

```
2000-12-16 12:21:13-05
```

From this I need

```
2000-12-16 12:21 (no seconds and milliseconds only date and time in hours and minutes)
```

From a timestamp with time zone field, say `update_time`, how do I get date as well as time like above using PostgreSQL select query.

Please help me.

Comment: Er ... `SELECT fieldname FROM table`. More details please, this doesn't make much sense as written. PostgreSQL version? Client program/driver you're using to access PostgreSQL? Code that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: try some of these: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are plenty of date-time functions available with postgresql:

See the list here

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

e.g.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 16
```

For formatting you can use these:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html

e.g.

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ...
```

Answer (score 23):

To get the `date` from a `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) a simple **cast** is fastest:

```
SELECT now()::date
```

You get the `date` according to your *local time zone* either way.

If you want `text` in a certain format, go with [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) like [@davek provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363091/939860).

If you want to truncate (round down) the value of a `timestamp` to a unit of time, use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', now());
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be enough:

```sql
select now()::date, now()::time
    , pg_typeof(now()), pg_typeof(now()::date), pg_typeof(now()::time)
```