# Grouping of PostgreSQL data

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a postgresql table which has events recorded by date/time. The table has the columns `id`, `event` and `timestamp`.

My output has to be something like this:

```
'Day', '1st Timers', '2nd Timers', '3rd Timers', '3+ Timers'
```

1st timers are all ids that have done the event for the first time.
2nd timers are all ids that have done the event for the second time. etc. etc.

Is this possible using a single SQL query?

edit: Sample data and output as per request

```
user_id date                event
1       09/03/15 14:08      opened
2      10/03/15 14:08       opened
1      11/03/15 14:08       opened
4      14/03/15 14:08       opened
1      15/03/15 14:08       opened
5      16/03/15 14:08       opened
1      17/03/15 14:08       opened
4      17/03/15 14:08       opened
6      18/03/15 14:08       opened
1      18/03/15 14:08       opened
6      18/03/15 14:08       other


Output (for event=opened)
date        1time   2times  3times  4times  5times
09/03/15    1       0       0       0       0
10/03/15    1       0       0       0       0
11/03/15    0       1       0       0       0
14/03/15    1       0       0       0       0
15/03/15    0       0       1       0       0
16/03/15    1       0       0       0       0
17/03/15    0       1       0       1       0
18/03/15    1       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample table data and expected output?

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres, please. It's relevant for the best solution.

Comment: If a user does an event two times on his/her first day, does (s)he count as "1st-timer" *and* "2nd-timer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each date, you seem to want to count the number of users that hit 1 time, 2 times, and so on.  I see this as a `row_number()` followed by conditional aggregation:

```
select thedate,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as time_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as time_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as time_3,
       sum(case when seqnum = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as time_4,
       sum(case when seqnum = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as time_5
from (select t.*, date_trunc('day', date) as thedate
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date_trunc('day', date)) as seqnum
      from table t
      where event = 'opened'
     ) t
group by thedate
order by thedate;
```

Comment: Clever use of `case` an `sum` with window functions

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be almost working.. The output I get is this http://pastebin.com/UyDYQ2pr. I believe the correct output for column2 is (column2 - column1). Some slight tweak is required, but not able to pin point.

Comment: @Anoop . . . I think you just want `where event = 'opened'`.

Comment: Correct. I figured it out. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Aggregate `FILTER`

Starting with Postgres 9.4 use the new aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT event_time::date
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) AS times_1
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE rn = 2) AS times_2
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE rn = 3) AS times_3
    -- etc.
from (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_time) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Related:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

About the cast `event_time::date`:

- [How to get the date and time from timestamp in PostgreSQL select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363023/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-from-timestamp-in-postgresql-select-query/17371452#17371452)

#### Crosstab

Or use an actual crosstab query (faster). Available for any modern Postgres version. **Read this first:**

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT event_time::date, rn, count(*)::int AS ct
        FROM  (
           SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_time) AS rn
           FROM   tbl
           ) t
        GROUP  BY 1, 2
        ORDER  BY 1'

      ,$$SELECT * FROM unnest ('{1,2,3}'::int[])$$
   ) AS ct (day date, times_1 int, times_2 int, times_3 int);
```

Comment: Thanks will try. That was just sample data I quickly cooked up, the actual field name is 'event_time'.

Comment: I'm using Amazon RedShift. I believe the crosstab and filter are not supported. :(

Comment: @Anoop: I believe that is something you should have told us up front. Redshift is not Postgres. I did ask for the version, too ...

Comment: Sorry about that. Very new to RedShift. I believed that the underlying DB was postgres without any differences.