# Sum with aggregate date postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, sum, aggregate

I have a table that has a column date and value, what I need is to sum a value showing just one date column.
Ex:
I have this:

```
date       value
2018-01-01 150
2018-01-23 140
```

what I need:

```
date    sum(value)
2018-01 290
```

Comment: What if you have a value for `2018-03-14`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution to get sums *per month*:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') AS mon, sum(value) AS sum_value
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

For large tables it's cheaper to group on `date_trunc('month', date)` instead.

Related:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)
- [Group and count events per time intervals, plus running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055461/group-and-count-events-per-time-intervals-plus-running-total/22055931#22055931)
- [How to get the date and time from timestamp in PostgreSQL select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363023/how-to-get-the-date-and-time-from-timestamp-in-postgresql-select-query/17371452#17371452)